# New to heroku and publishing websites wanting to know the best plan/dyno-type to choose for large 203mb django website

Tags: django, heroku, heroku-postgres, heroku-cli, dyno

I have a Django website that I want to publish, the size of the file being pushed to Heroku is 203 Mb (memory quota vastly exceeded when using the free version). I will also require the Heroku app to temporarily store CSV files that can range from 80kb to 10Mb as well as user login information. If anyone could recommend a plan/dyno-type to use that at least meets the storage requirements that'll be greatly appreciated. thank you!

Comment: I believe Heroku support can be more helpful on this.

Comment: yeh on the heroku support it gives the option to ask the community (stackoverflow), but none to ask the team from what i saw. @Selcuk thank you